# Apache Camel 2.18.0 Consumer does not consume

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel

We are using apache camel to 2.17.* version inorder to utilize the maxPollRecords parameter I am trying to upgrade to 2.18.0.  Post upgrade to 2.18.0 The consumer doesn't seems to be recognized by the broker anymore. Following is the sample consumer I tried to create. I could produce the message from cli to the topic and if I create a consumer in the cli I could see the consumer created in cli consumes the message but not the consumer created through apache camel.

Also with the consumer group describe cli command I could see the consumer-id as blank if I run only apache camel consumer instance. While I was running with 2.17.5 the broker used to recognize and assign that to the partition. I can't find the example
please help.

```
package com.test;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Message;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class CamelConsumer {

public static void main(String argv[]){
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

// Add route to send messages to Kafka

try {
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
public void configure() {
PropertiesComponent pc = getContext().getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
pc.setLocation("classpath:application.properties");

System.out.println("About to start route: Kafka Server -> Log ");


from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
+ "&maxPollRecords={{consumer.maxPollRecords}}" + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}"
+ "&groupId={{consumer.group}}").routeId("FromKafka")
.process(new Processor() {

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

Message message = exchange.getIn();
Object data = message.getBody();

System.out.println(data);
}
});
}
});

camelContext.start();

Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);

camelContext.stop();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

I donot get any exception either. I donot find any documentation related to this. Please help.

> consumer.topic=test kafka.host=localhost kafka.port=9092
> consumer.maxPollRecords=1 consumer.consumersCount=1
> consumer.group=test

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem ?

Comment: I could find the sample program from 2.19 in the https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/branches (Forked branch) link. I could see those are working fine. But now when I try to implement the same in the application while i run the describe command for the group I have started I could always see the consumer-id filed as blank                                                                                                                 
GROUP                     TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID

Answer (score 0):

I could find out the working example code from 2.19* in the following repository.
https://github.com/Talend/apache-camel/branches (Forked branch)

https://github.com/apache/camel (actual camel branch)

Finally it worked with the version 2.21.5 and I had to bump up the apache kafka maven version to 1.0.0 from 0.9*